# How urgently does this damaged joist need to be repaired?

Tags: framing

I am the owner of a century home and I am in the process of getting my insulation replaced. I ventured into the attic to check out the clean-up work of contractors and noticed something off: it looks like the previous owners had some electrical work done which resulted in the ceiling joist getting cut into in order to fit an electrical box for the hood vent.

How urgently does this need to be repaired? Is this a DIY fix, or something I should call in a professional for? I've read online about "sistering the damaged wood" but wasn't sure if that would work here since the box is in the way.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

[image: damaged wood]

Comment: A ceiling joist does not have the same weight problems as a floor joist, so not nice to make such a big hole, but less important than in a floor joist.  A piece of flat steel or angle iron screw into the top should be enough if worried about it.

Answer (score 2):

The International Residential Code's maximum notch depth is 1/6 times the joist height, where the notch can't be in the middle third of the joist's span. See [IRC R502.8](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.8) (technically R502.8 gets referenced from the actual governing part at R802.7.1, but I doubt you want to trace the reference yourself). Your notch is clearly out of spec and the work appears relatively recent.

The flanking joists of this notched joist are holding it and you up when you put weight on the notched joist. That's 100% + 50% load on each flanking joist. Is it okay under normal conditions with nobody in the attic? You bet. Is it okay under construction conditions with people working around it? This is the most likely circumstance that would cause a failure, but it looks like it is doing well.

The ceiling carries most load on the notched joist to the flanking joists. I would be tempted to relieve this stress in the ceiling by bearing a 2×6 flat on top of the flanking joists and the notched joist, and then screwing down into the notched joist from above with 2 or 3 screws. One 2×6 just to the side of the electric box would be sufficient to avoid any accidents where somebody steps right on the notch, but I would probably implement the detail on both sides of the notch for appearances.

Comment: Does this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/1aOrcA4) accurately capture your suggestion @popham? If so, how far do you suggesting having the 2x6 placed from the joist with the hole in it (6 inches, 12, inches, etc.)? Also, excuse me if this is a stupid question, but I'm assuming in addition to the black screws in the picture, the blue screws are recommended as well? And lastly, screws over nails?

Comment: As far as screws rather than nails, you don't want to be hammering on ceiling joists with ceiling in place because it can fracture or loosen joints or plaster. You would need only one small screw into each of the flanking joists because those screws would be under low stress. They are there just to prevent twisting. The screws into the notched joist should be decent structural screws.

Comment: @Austin, +1 on Jim's comment. Using the trashiest species possible, Spruce-Pine-Fir (South), the AWC's [connection calculator](https://awc.org/calculators/connection-calculator/) spits out 105# withdrawal strength for 3" long #10 screws, so the 2 or 3 screws provide better than 200# to 300# of withdrawal strength. This withdrawal strength fights against sagging of the notched joist. The 2x6 bears on top of the flanking joists in compression under the notched joist's sagging, so those fasteners are trivial.

Comment: @Austin, your picture is perfect, although I would put a 2x6 on both sides of the notch instead of just the one. Installing the 2x6 closer to the notch is better, but I wouldn't crowd the electric box. I would probably offset it with something like a 3" gap between the edge of the box and the edge of the 2x6. Nothing scientific, though. Just enough space to fuss with the electric box if ever necessary.